# date formatting in sapui5

Tags: sapui5, date-formatting

I have this date coming in the json- startDate: "2014-12-07T00:00:00" and the view should render this as- Dec 7, 2014.
and I used the follwoing to format it.

```
text="{ path: 'startDate',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
        formatOptions: {
                source: {pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'}, 
                style: 'medium'
       }}"
```

I am not clear how this date formatting works. I mean what is the pattern that needs to be given?
Please help me with this. thanks !

Comment: the pattern in `source` specifies how the source is to be parsed. There is supposedly `destination` or `display` property where you can also specify the output format. If you are looking for the output format, its `MMM dd,YYYY`

Comment: The output source is the property style specified - so when I checked the sap demo kit, i saw that style 'medium' renders it the mmm dd,yyyy format. I was confused about the pattern value as the ones given in the documentation were not matching with the pattern I was getting in my json. It worked when i changed it to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss format :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to Date in SAPUI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343915/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-sapui5)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem of parsing JSON formatted dates. In my case the string is like

```js
JSON.stringify(new Date(Date.now()));
// returns "2018-03-06T05:20:16.143Z"
new Date(Date.now()).toISOString();
// returns 2018-03-06T05:20:16.143Z
```

which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) has been standard in ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262). The correct pattern to use in this case is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSX`.

```xml
<Text text="{ path: 'myDateTime',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime',
    formatOptions: {
        source: {pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSX'},
        style: 'medium'
    }}"/>
```

Also, if your JSON uses a different notation, you can build your own pattern according to this: [Date Field Symbol Table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

I hope this can help anyone who comes across this dealing with JSON formatted DateTime value.

Answer (score 0):

it worked when i made the pattern to this yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Given your startDate: "2014-12-07T00:00:00", I would suggest using the source pattern as mentioned in the snippet below (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss) as it matches your source date.

And instead of using 'style' attribute, go the old fashion way. 
So, in your case, the pattern 'MMM dd, yyyy' should do the job.

```
<Text text="{path : 'startDate', 
type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', 
formatOptions: 
 { 
 source : 
  {
  pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss' 
  },
 pattern: 'MMM dd, yyyy'
 }
} 
"/>
```

For modifications in the pattern, I would recommend using the date format abbreviations mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)