# How to convert datetime string to date in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, sapui5

I am trying to convert String to Date in SAPUI5

```
var Fdate = "2020-08-01T00:00:00";
var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
    pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy"
});
fdateFormatted = dateFormat.format(Fdate);
```

But this returns the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: j.getTime is not a function

I tried to set the source pattern as "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss". But this returns the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In JS

```
// DateFormat required from "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
const dt = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({ pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy" });
const jsDateObject = dt.parse("2020-08-01T00:00:00"); // returns: Sat Aug 01 2020 00:00:00 <timezone information>
const dayMonthYear = dt.format(jsDateObject) // returns: "01/08/2020"
```

- If the string contains date **and** time, parse it via a *date time instance*.[<sup>api</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat#methods/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance)
- `.parse`[<sup>api</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat#methods/parse) awaits a string value and converts it into a JS date (e.g. for storing it in a model).
- `.format`[<sup>api</sup>](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat#methods/format) awaits a JS date and converts it into a string representation (e.g. for displaying it in the UI).

---

### In Two Way data binding (Model-View-ViewModel pattern)

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131534/5846045:

```xml
<DatePicker value="{
  path: '/MyDateTimeString',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
  formatOptions: {
    source: {
      pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
    }
  }
}" />
```

The framework will then use `.format` and `.parse` automatically. I.e. users can pick or enter a date in the UI, and the input will be then parsed and stored as a JS date in the model without writing a single line of JS code.

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel", // sample model. Works also with ODataModel.
], (XMLView, MyModel) => XMLView.create({
  definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <VBox xmlns="sap.m" class="sapUiTinyMargin">
      <DatePicker
        width="12rem"
        value="{
          path: '/MyDateTimeString',
          type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
          formatOptions: {
            source: {
              pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
            }
          }
        }"
      />
      <ObjectAttribute
        title="Model"
        text="&#34;{/MyDateTimeString}&#34;"
      />
    </VBox>
  </mvc:View>`,
  models: new MyModel({ // e.g. v2.ODataModel
    MyDateTimeString: "2020-08-01T00:00:00", // Type="Edm.String"
  }),
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script><body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

<sup>Click "Show code snippet" and <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see the demo in action.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The formater function expects a date object.

```
var Fdate = "2020-08-01T00:00:00";
var date = new Date(Fdate);
var dateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
    pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy"
});
fdateFormatted = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Does JavaScript Date behave differently if placed within an OData call? Actually, I am trying this conversion within an OData's success method. Somehow I am not able to use JavaScript's Date there.

Comment: Marc ah yes thanks, fixed the answer :) @d33a I don't understand your question, for .create, .update, etc requests I just pass the date object and the framework transforms it to something like "\/Date(1596232800000)\/" if I recall correctly.

Comment: @d33a Since the question about the OData is a distinct different question, please open a new question with more details.